# External Hard drive wont read

Tags: hard-drive, samba

So I had a Dell Poweredge r210 running as a Samba server on my home network and the other day the power cut in and out about 3 times relatively quickly. Ever since then I have not been able to get the server to start up. So I purchased [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FDLCTQO) external hard drive reader so I could pull files off the drive while I work on fixing the actual server .

The problem here is that windows does not seem to be able to read the disk. It shows up in the Disk Management menu and in the Devices menu, but when I look for it using file explorer there's nothing there. I tried updating my windows and relevant drivers but still nothing... any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sure that you are using windows to look at a linux filesystem. You didn't specify, but SAMBA gave it away. Windows isn't capable of reading linux filesystems like ext4 by itself. There are some drivers/helper programs that allow it to do that. For example: http://www.ext2fsd.com/. I have no experience with it and wouldn't recommend using windows for that task.

I would recommend using a linux workstation, live cd or similar to retrieve/backup the data. However it still could be lost.

Comment: ah I totally forgot linux file systems are different, I'll try booting a live Linux os